# Can you draw a "Four Roofed Crossed Square" without lifting your pencil?

Tags: pencil-and-paper-games

The puzzle I am trying to solve is where you must successfully draw a geometric object without lifting your pencil or running over previous lines. Can you solve it for the following:
[image: The "Four Roofed Crossed Square" Challenge]